# Creating script for multiple sql files in DB2 iseries

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'd like to create an sql file to execute multiple other sql files.
In order to run or "deploy" the files correctly.

I usually (in oracle) did something like:

```
@/location/table1.sql  
@/location/table1triggers.sql  
@/location/table1index's.sql  
@/location/table2.sql  
@/location/table2triggers.sql  
@/location/table2index's.sql  
@/location/table1constraints.sql (FK for table 2)
```

And then just executed that whole file, is there anything like that for db2 iseries / ibm?

Comment: Do you plan to submit the scripts from a Windows/Linux client, or natively on i-Series ?  Give details.

Comment: @mao I use the "IBM i Access Client Solutions" to develope in, so i guess submitting from Windows yes.

Comment: For Windows, any scripting language (python, perl, php, CMD, powershell etc) can be used against remote Db2-databases, once properly configured. So choose your scripting method and get busy.  Alternatively script on iSeries directly as per jmarkmurphy answer. Depends on skills and deployment-requirements.

Comment: @mao so I'm required to do another scripting language than SQL. Okay thanks, not what I was hoping though.

Comment: You can also script with Db2 CLPPlus (which has some similarity with Oracle SQLPlus) and use it against remote databases.

Comment: IRL put all the statements for table1 in one file.  Put all the statements for table2 in one file.  Separate statements with a;  Put the fk statements in the parent file.  IRL never would I make a program to run scripts to create a table.  I would just execute the one script for the table.  Who wants to create a program just to create a table.  Who would want to create extra work like that?

Comment: I can't try it out myself right now, but have you looked at kicking off ACS from the command line to 'Run SQL Script' specifying a specific sql script? The ACS Getting Started documentation (section 9.1.31 in the version I've just downloaded) definitely implies this is possible. You could then sequence multiple such invocations in a .bat file.

Comment: @danny117 that was exactly my thought when i saw mao's answer. I don't want to make a program, also because it requires me to learn a new language ;-)

Comment: @MandyShaw i fail to see what you are refering too, can you be more precise?

Comment: You have mentioned that you wish to use IBM i Access Client Solutions (ACS). I am suggesting that you use its command line switches to kick off exactly the sql script you require, automatically, from a Windows command prompt /or/ from a .bat file which you can sequence as you wish. Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't do you an example because I don't have an IBM i partition I can connect to right now, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

On IBM i, I would do that by creating a CL Program that runs each script like this:

```
RUNSQLSTM SRCSTMF('/location/table1.sql')
RUNSQLSTM SRCSTMF('/location/table1triggers.sql')
RUNSQLSTM SRCSTMF('/location/table1indexes.sql')
RUNSQLSTM SRCSTMF('/location/table2.sql')
RUNSQLSTM SRCSTMF('/location/table2triggers.sql')
RUNSQLSTM SRCSTMF('/location/table2indexes.sql')
RUNSQLSTM SRCSTMF('/location/table1constraints.sql') /* FK for table 2 */
```

This would then be compiled into a program using the `CRTCLPGM` command, then executed using the `CALL` command.

Though there is an `INCLUDE` statement in the DB2 for i syntax, that can only be embedded in programs written RPG, COBOL, or C.